# Change z axis for camera

Tags: camera

How can I change the camera' z axis? Right the picture it is taking is to long and I want it to be shorter on the z axis?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

so you need to go into Output Properties [image]
and just change Resolution X (as marked in the screenshot) to a higher value
(or you can also change the Resolution Y to a lower value)
to scale down the camera on the Z-axis.
[image: Here I changed the Resolution X value to show you and example.]

I hope this helped you.

Comment: It helped! thank you very much :)

Comment: Your welcome Accepting the answer would be very much aprecciated